# Partition not showing showing data properly

Tags: linux, centos, aws

I have an aws centos 7 ec2 instance with an EBS volume attached to it. The volume was partitioned with fdisk. There is only one primary partition with an *ext4* filesystem.

Everything was going fine, data was all there on */dev/xvdb1* when I mounted it. I powered down my instance over the weekend and now when I mount nothing shows up on */dev/xvdb1* but when I mount */dev/xvdb* all my data is there. No errors show up when I do an *fsck.ext4* or when I check parted or *partprobe*.  Is this a case of a bad partition table?